# How to make an animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, ode, subplot

Help!
I am trying to make a function that animates the solution to the differential equation, however it does not show me any animation. Is there something wrong?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

def animation(res, cap, l, i, fem):
    neper_frec = float(res / l)
    nat_frec = float(1/(cap*1)
    initial_charge = float(cap*fem)
    interval = np.linspace(0, 10, 600)
    def ode(y, t):
        charge, current = y
        dydt = [current, -neper_frec*current - nat_frec*charge]
        return dydt
    y0 = [initial_charge, i]
    sol = odeint(EDO, y0, interval)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set(xlim=(0, 10), ylim=(-initial_charge, initial_charge))
    line, = ax.plot([], [])

    y = sol[:, 0]
    def animate(i):
        line.set_data(interval[:i], y[:i])
        return line,
    anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames = len(interval) + 1, interval = 20, blit = True)
    plt.show()

#animacion(1.4, 1/600, 1.7, 0.5, 8)
```

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Always provide a complete [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, only plot images are okay.

Comment: Where is the code that calls function `def animation(res, cap, l, i, fem)`??  If this is all of your code, you are only defining a function, not calling it.

Comment: If I uncomment `#animacion(1.4, 1/600, 1.7, 0.5, 8)` and fix the spelling to `animation()`, then I get  `File "tmp_anim.py", line 16, in animation
    sol = odeint(EDO, y0, interval)
NameError: name 'EDO' is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

1. uncomment `#animacion(1.4, 1/600, 1.7, 0.5, 8)`
2. correct spelling to `animation(1.4, 1/600, 1.7, 0.5, 8)`
3. correct typo `EDO` to `ode` in line:

```py
sol = odeint(ode, y0, interval)
```

Then animation works fine!